switching from windows to linux for selenium java, how can i resolve this error?
I've been using selenium on windows for a while, but recently switched to linux and I have an issue with launching the web browser in eclipse using selenium.
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver ();
driver.get("google.com");

and the error I'm getting:
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /home/meerkat/.cache/selenium/chrome/linux64/126.0.6478.126/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.) 
Host info: host: 'meerkat', ip: '127.0.1.1'
Build info: version: '4.21.0', revision: '79ed462ef4'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.15.0-112-generic', java.version: '21.0.3'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [], binary: /home/meerkat/.cache/seleni..., extensions: []}}]}]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:114)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:75)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:61)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:162)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:174)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:518)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:232)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:161)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:114)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:88)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:51)
    at programme.mainClass.main(mainClass.java:12)

Tried launching a server with
xvfb-run java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/usr/bin/chromedriver -jar selenium-server.jar

That didn't help either.
Tried following few tutorials but no luck.
